# How to set scheduler for rest api call each day at specific time for iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift3, ios9, ios10, background-process

I have to schedule one web service api call each day at fix time let's say 9 AM (app may be in running, background or not running
 states), and based on response I have to show local notification at 10
 AM.
       I am currently working with Swift3 and Xcode8.2.1 and minimum deployment target is iOS9.

1. Any idea how we can achieve this ?, your suggestions would be
               help-full for me.
2. Is this really possible without help of APNS
               service ?

Comment: You can send push with **content-available**. The system load you application in background mode and your program a have time to download new content. I think it's will help you.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but @Sergey,  I have to manage this functionality locally in app without help of APNS. is this possible ?

Comment: I have not done anything like this before.. But once I looked at one of the WWDC video and in this video tells about some smart system scheduler that watch for user and launch the application in background for update content before user run it. But I do not remember which video this is.